Cannot export a typescript interface created via declaration merging
I'm building a package that uses declaration merging to build up an interface across a few files. Here's a basic reproduction:
Background
MyType.ts - contains an empty interface we will contribute new properties to via declaration merging in other files
export interface MyType {}

merged.ts - an example file which merges properties onto the MyType interface
import "./MyType";

declare module "./MyType" {
  interface MyType {
    foo: string;
  }
}

index.ts - the entrypoint for building the package
import { MyType } from "./MyType";
import "./merged";

export type MyTypeKeys = keyof MyType;
//           ^? type MyTypeKeys = "foo"


The declaration merging works. You can see that the MyTypeKeys properly contains foo:
Problem
However once I build this package using tsup, the declaration merging is lost in the compiled index.d.ts file:
index.d.ts - the compiled type declaration file
interface MyType {
}

declare module "./MyType" {
    interface MyType {
        foo: string;
    }
}

type MyTypeKeys = keyof MyType;
//   ^? type MyTypeKeys = never

export type { MyTypeKeys };

Conclusion
I expected the compiled index.d.ts file would contain a merged interface instead of preserving the declare module stuff. Is there something I'm missing?
Here is my tsconfig.json:
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig",
  "include": ["src"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "declaration": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "ESNext"
  }
}


I provided them as supplementary. The entire code is also included in plaintext above the screenshots.

Can you demonstrate this via a web IDE project? If I take your code as-is and put it into the TS Bug Workbench, I'm not seeing the compiled declaration file showing what you're showing, probably because there are compiler options that differ from what you're doing. Look at this bug workbench link and see the Debug tab in the righthand pane, and scroll down to the index.d.ts output. If you can demonstrate the issue in a web IDE or give enough compiler info for others to repro, that would be helpful. Otherwise this might not be a [mre].

Thanks for the link to the Debug workbench. Where is the tsconfig.json the workbench is using?

It uses twoslash directives and not a tsconfig.json file, as described in the docs on the page. If you want to reproduce it with a more traditional build you might want to use something like codesandbox or stackblitz instead of the bug workbench.

I've added my tsconfig.json and removed the screenshots. I'm not able to use codesandbox because it doesn't let you run your own scripts in package.json.

Huh, well unless I can see it happen in front of me I'm probably not of much use, and so far I've failed to get it to reproduce. I'll disengage unless I see an [edit] that changes this. Good luck!

I think the issue is with tsup, when i build using tsc it works.

Ah then you probably want to put that in the question body and  tag it with tsup to get the right eyes on the question, since the issue isn’t with the TypeScript language or the TypeScript compiler.
